# as.Date with dates in format m/d/y in R

Tags: r, date, r-faq

A client sent me an Excel file with dates formatted as e.g 3/15/2012 for March 15. I saved this as a .csv file and then used

```
camm$Date <- as.Date(camm$Date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

but this gave me values starting in the year 2020!

I tried to reformat the dates in the original csv file so that they were e.g. 03/14/2013 but was unable to do so.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Did you try a capital `%Y`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use capital `Y` in `as.Date` call instead. This should do the trick:

```
> as.Date("3/15/2012", "%m/%d/%Y")
[1] "2012-03-15"
```

From the help file's examples you can realize when year is full specified you should use `%Y` otherwise `%y` for example:

```
> dates <- c("02/27/92", "02/27/92", "01/14/92", "02/28/92", "02/01/92")
> as.Date(dates, "%m/%d/%y")
[1] "1992-02-27" "1992-02-27" "1992-01-14" "1992-02-28" "1992-02-01"
```

You can see that in your example the Year format is 2012 then you should use `%Y`, and in the other example (taken from the `as.Date` help file) Year format is 92 then using `%y` is the correct way to go. See `as.Date` for further details.

Answer (score 2):

You might also give a try to the `lubridate` package if you do not want to deal with the hieroglyphics :)

```
> library(lubridate)
> parse_date_time('3/15/2012', 'mdy')
 1 parsed with %m/%d/%Y
[1] "2012-03-15 UTC"
```

---

PS.: of course I do not encourage anyone to use any extra dependencies, this answer was just posted here as an alternative (and quick to remeber) solution

Answer (score 1):

To complete the picture, you might also try the recently introduced (2016-09) package `anytime` which takes advantage of the `Boost` C++ libraries:

```
anytime::anytime("3/15/2012")
#[1] "2012-03-15 CET"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `mdy` from `lubridate`

```
lubridate::mdy('3/15/2012')
#[1] "2012-03-15"
```

Or `parse_date` from `readr` which uses same format as `as.Date`

```
readr::parse_date('3/15/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
#[1] "2012-03-15"
```