# How to convert this timestamp format to standard timestamp format?

Tags: r, timestamp

The timestamps I have as character class are in this format: 1/28/15 16:34 . How do I covert it to an R time stamp format and then also extract the hour of the day, day of the week and year separately as well?

Comment: `strptime('1/28/15 16:34', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')`

Comment: Also how do i extract time of day and day of week and year into 3 separate variables after this conversion? I say after conversion as I also need the complete timestamp which you provided in your answer very well. Also, why is everyone downvoting me!!!

Comment: `strptime('1/28/15 16:34', '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')$wday` gives `3` (which is wednesday)

Comment: The reason is quite obvious to me: you didn't show any research effort (which is also suggested when you hover over the downvote button). Just typing the [two tags in the search box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+timestamp) would have given you a nice collection of answers on converting character strings to datetime format. See also: [ask].

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15072955/3817004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strptime` function in this way:

```
my_time = strptime("1/28/15 16:34", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Note in particular the `%m` and the `%y` to say, respectively, that months will be written with 1 character from Jan to Sept and year will be written with 2 character.

For example, if you need to convert "01/28/2015" you need `%M` and `%Y`:

```
my_time = strptime('01/28/2015 16:34', '%M/%d/%Y %H:%M')
```

To extract the day of week and the hour:

```
library(lubridate)
week_day = wday(my_time) # or wday(my_time, label=T) if you want the weekday label (Wed in this case)
day_hour = hour(my_time)
```

Comment: Also how do i extract time of day and day of week and year into 3 separate variables after this conversion? I say after conversion as I also need the complete timestamp which you provided in your answer very well. Also, why is everyone downvoting me!!!